# Yii Mysql Select Custom Field

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I would to have 2 custom fields based in one field.
How can I do that?

---

Code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select='(number*2) AS custom_field, (number*4) AS custom_field';
$criteria->order='custom_field';
$model = Events::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Table:

```
number   custom_field
------------------
2         4, 8
3         6, 12

custom_field ordered -> 4, 6, 8, 12
```

---

Edit:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'id'=>'recurringevents-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'custom_field',
    ),
)); ?>
```

Output:

```
Custom Field
4
6
8
12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st. Events.php

```
class Events extends CActiveRecord {
    public $custom_square, $custome_square_square;
// skip ...
    public funciton rules() {
    // skip ...
          array('custom_square, custom_square_square', 'safe'),
```

2nd. Separate sql select:

```
$criteria->select = array(
    new CDbExpression('(number*2) AS custom_square'), 
    new CDbExpression('(number*4) AS custom_square_square'),
);
$criteria->order='custom_square';
$model = Events::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: thx to help me again! Please check the edit in the original post, how can I list 2 different fields in same `TbGridView` ordered?